# Bootable flashdrive

Tags: boot, system-installation, wine

I had Linux for a while and just can't get used to it. I liked Ubuntu better, so I wanted to get it back.

I downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 and also the universal USB installer from pendrivelinux.com to my computer.

First, I couldn't run the installer because I needed an application for it, so I installed WINE.

I was able to run the installer with that and I would've only have to select 3 things:

1. The Linux distribution.
2. The ISO.
3. Select the USB.

Nothing happened when I clicked on the arrow to select the USB. THere just weren't any options. I tried adding it to Dropbox by using WINE as well, but no luck.

Does anybody know any other ways to save Ubuntu to my flashdrive so i can try to install it from there?

Comment: What distribution is this `linux` you have installed ?

Comment: The one i have right now its linux mint

Comment: I think linux mint has the `start up disk creator` application, does it not ? Look in your applications or I think (long time since I tried Mint) Control centre ?

Comment: What I would really recommend is unedbootn, or if you have an ISO just the standard disk manager and write an image to the flash drive

Comment: I cant believe i didnt even check for that. Thank you very muchhhh! :D

Comment: Any step by step tutorial you would recommend for after that? I just wrote the ISO file in the USB, but Im not really sure what to do now. Thank you!

Comment: You just want too install Ubuntu now ? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make a bootable Ubuntu installation with a Windows utility from Linux Mint is not going to work. Linux Mint comes with a graphical startup disk creation tool if you need a GUI.

In my opinion it's better to do this from the terminal however.
Open a terminal emulator and run: `sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX` where sdX is the device name of your USB stick. This is usually NOT `sda`. Make sure you have the right device before running the command.

Comment: Or do this graphically, using the Gnome Disk Utility ('disks'). *Simply click on 'cog' icon (top right), and 'restore' .ISO to the USB (overwriting all data).* **Make sure you have the right device.**